# Why atomic overloads for shared_ptr exist

Tags: c++, c++11, shared-ptr, smart-pointers

Why are there are atomic overloads for `shared_ptr` as described [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/atomic) rather than there being a specialization for `std::atomic` which deals with `shared_ptr`s.  Seems inconsistent with the object oriented patterns employed by the rest of the C++ standard library..

And just to make sure I am getting this right, when using `shared_ptr`s to implement the [read copy update idiom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Read-copy-update) we need to do all accesses (reads and writes) to shared pointers through these functions right?

Comment: I don't think C++ standard library is meant to be OO.

Comment: Concurrency TS has `atomic_shared_ptr` to fix this oversight in the standard.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because:

> std::atomic may be instantiated with any TriviallyCopyable type T.

Source: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic

And

```
std::is_trivially_copyable<std::shared_ptr<int>>::value == false;
```

Thus, you cannot instantiate `std::atomic<>` with `std::shared_ptr<>`. However, automatic memory management is useful in multi-threading, thus those overloads were provided. Those overloads are most likely not lock-free however (one of the big draws of using `std::atomic<>` in the first place); they probably use a lock to provide synchronicity.

As for your second question: yes.

Comment: Well they are still atomic. But they are not [lock-free](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic/is_lock_free).

Comment: @ysdx You're right, I kind of mixed both together and I wasn't accurate. Fixed.